# Finding the first div inside a td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pointing at the first div inside my table's td as you can see in the jQuery code below.

```
$('table tr td div').css("position", "relative");
```

But I've got some problems with that so I've tried this:

```
$('table tr td').parents('div:first').css({position:'relative'});
```

But this one doesn't work fine either. What is wrong with my code?

My HTML structure is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><!-- all id for the div and image inside the td are dynamic -->
            <div><!-- Need to access this div -->
                <!-- content --->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to find each first div in each td or just the first of all divs?

Comment: @FelixKling: yes i need to find each first div in the each td

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.parents()` find all parent of your selection. what you want is a child.

```
$('table tr td div:first').css("position", "relative");
```

This will do the trick for you :)

---

You also might want to select only exact descendants, in that case you can use:

```
$('table tr td > div:first').css("position", "relative");
```

Comment: Also, you might want to select only the exact descendants, in that cas you can use "table tr td>div"

Comment: you mean `"table tr td>div:first"`

Comment: As suggested by jQuery documentation, jQuery("table tr td div").filter(":first") is faster. when handling heavy DOM tree.

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel sorry but I don't believe in that. Can you post a link?

Comment: Krish: Yes :) I was focusing on the adding of a '>' more than the full selector :) Guillaume: I wasn't aware. Either way, I would already suggest working by ID or class (e.g. for the table). That should also increase the efficiency by a nice factor :)

Comment: Sure! Here is the link : http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/ See "Additional Notes" there. Working with ID for the table would be way better indeed.

Comment: So Krish, I think the combined result would be: jQuery("#my_table tr td div").filter(":first"). An ID or class for the div would be beter, but this should get you a nice and efficient selector already.

Answer (score 0):

You could use below 2 methods if you want to find the occurrence of the first DIV from TD with the class'vx1'

```
$( "table tr td.vx1 > div:first" ).css( "width", "50" );
```

You could use below 2 methods if you want to find the occurrence of the first DIV from TH with the class'vx1'

```
$( "table tr th.vx1 > div:first" ).css( "width", "50" );
```